# Loomis and Sternberg Problem 1.13

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces, problem-solving

**Advanced Calculus by Loomis & Sternberg Problem 1.13:**

> Let $V$ be $\mathbb{R^2}$, and let $M$ be the line through the origin with slope $k$. Let $\mathbf{x}$ be any nonzero vector in $M$. Show that $M$ is the subspace $\mathbb{R} \mathbf{x} = \{t \mathbf{x} : t \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Could you please give me some hints for this problem?

Edit - Managed to solve it using the hints [GEdgar](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/442/gedgar) gave below. Here is my solution:

**Proving $\ \mathbb{R}M \subseteq M$**

Because $M$ is the line through the origin with slope $k$, $M$ is the set of all tuples $<a,b>$ that satisfies $b=ka$.

We know that $\mathbf{x}=<x,y>$ is in $M$ so $y=kx$. But then $t\mathbf{x}=<tx, ty>$ $\in M$ since $ty=t(kx)=k(tx)$. Therefore $\mathbb{R}\mathbf{x} \subseteq M $.

**Proving $\ M \subseteq \mathbb{R}M $**

Since $\mathbf{x}=<x,y>$ is non-zero, either $x \neq 0$ or $y \neq 0$ is true. Also, since $\mathbf{x} \in M$, $y=kx$.

*If $x \neq 0$ is true -* Take any $\mathbf{u}=<u_1,u_2> \in M$. Then $\ u_2=ku_1$. Since $x \neq 0$, $\ k=y/x$. So $u_2=y * u_1 / x$. Therefore $(u_1/x)*<x,y>$ is equal to $<u_1, u_2>$ so $\mathbf{u} \in \mathbb{R}\mathbf{x}$.

Similarly for $y \neq 0$.

Thus $M \subseteq \mathbb{R}M$. $\square$

Comment: Hint: to prove equality of two sets, show that each is a subset of the other.  Show $M \subseteq \mathbb R\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbb R\mathbf{x} \subseteq M$.  Show your efforts in the problem (otherwise, the problem is likely to be closed).

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks for the hint. I have added my progress to the post

Comment: Good, you are half done!

Comment: @GEdgar :) The other half is proving to be a bit difficult for me. Do you have some pointers for me by any chance?

Comment: To prove $M \subseteq \mathbb R\mathbf{x}$:   Let $\mathbf u$ be an element of $M$.  Show $\mathbf u$ is an element of $ \mathbb R\mathbf{x}$.  Here, you will nave to use the fact that $\mathbf x$ is nonzero.

Comment: @GEdgar I finally got it! Thank you so much. Really appreciate it